using the bb[warn|debug|note] command in a recipe file in BitBake
I am getting this error from the console logs on my build:
18:59:47 Parsing recipes...ERROR: ParseError at /vol/lib/jobs/hercules-next/jobs/master/workspace/yocto/meta-lf/meta-hercules/recipes-platform/lfutils/lfutils_1.0.0.bb:26: unparsed line: 'bbwarn "Hello, World!"'
And here are the lines in my  bitbake recipe.
#
# experimental logging commands.
#
inherit logging
bbwarn "Hello, World!"
bbwarn "PN: ${PN} SRC_URI: ${SRC_URI} SRCREV: ${SRCREV} PV: ${PV} WORKDIR: ${WORKDIR}"

Notice how I went for the old and true classic "Hello, world!" without any variables to verify that bbwarn itself is failing.
Thanks,
Tom
Tried to use bbwarn and was expecting some tasty logging output in my jenkins console log file and instead got an error and the build failed.

I think you need to use log functions in tasks (do_fetch, do_install, do_compile...).
